# Excel 2010 spreadsheet's single worksheet into .csv format

Tags: excel

How to convert & save a single worksheet of a excel 2010 workbook into .csv format.
the worksheet contains almost 10 worksheets, and i just want to convert & save a single worksheet into .csv format

Answer (score 1):

This will happen by default when you use "save As" and select CSV.  Only the current worksheet will be saved.

Answer (score 0):

Try using PHP-ExcelReader.It has  methods to get number of sheets and all data in corresponding sheet.
You may have to rename one of the file  inclu(If you are downloading from source forge)from .inc to .php